# How to plot from pandas dataframe with coordinates on same line?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have an issue which I can solve in a quite difficult way, but I am looking for any alternative solution.

I have a dataset like this:

```
City    x-Coord     y-Coord coord       combined    angle   difference_cities   prev city coordinate    rank by distance
70  49.0        96.0    (49+96j)    [49.0, 96.0]    158     4.243           [52.0, 99.0]        1.0
37  76.0        19.0    (76+19j)    [76.0, 19.0]    151     5.000           [80.0, 16.0]        2.0
71  55.0        80.0    (55+80j)    [55.0, 80.0]    114     5.000           [59.0, 77.0]        2.0
32  27.0        144.0   (27+144j)   [27.0, 144.0]   101     5.657           [31.0, 140.0]       3.0
81  33.0        177.0   (33+177j)   [33.0, 177.0]   100     5.831           [36.0, 172.0]       4.0
```

Mainly, co-ordinates of every point is given by column combined, (x,y), the point to be joined is in "prev city coordinate". Example: (49,96) to be joined with (52.99) and so on.

I know that we can do pandas plot of joining x and y axis points from 2 separate columns(pandas.plot). I can a imagine a very difficult way of doing things here, but is there any other way or any idea how I should proceed in the above example.

Thanks a lot,

Sudip

Comment: What do you mean by "joining"?

Comment: I mean, I intend to plot 5 lines, first line connecting (49,96) and (52,99). second line connecting (76,19) and (80,16). 3rd connecting (55,80) and (59,77) and so forth.

Comment: Have you checked GeoPandas? http://geopandas.org/geometric_manipulations.html seems to have some straigthforward plotting utilities for what you are looking for.

Comment: Actually, I already have a plot from another dataframe on which this has to be superimposed. Hence, I cannot use the method that you have suggested. But thanks a lot for the suggestion.